# Code for multilingual support in android

Tags: android, localization, multilingual

I need to develop an application which works in English and Japanese both.

I need language change for only my application and rest all other phone applications should be in default language.

Please help me with some code snippet / apis to use in android 2.2

Comment: What do you mean ? do you want your application to only support Japanese and English ? or do you need to be able to switch between english and Japanese withing your app

Answer (score 5):

[Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) is what you need!

> A large part of localizing an
>   application is providing alternative
>   text for different languages. In some
>   cases you will also provide
>   alternative graphics, sounds, layouts,
>   and other locale-specific resources.
>
> An application can specify many
>   res// directories, each
>   with different qualifiers. To create
>   an alternative resource for a
>   different locale, you use a qualifier
>   that specifies a language or a
>   language-region combination. (The name
>   of a resource directory must conform
>   to the naming scheme described in
>   Providing Alternative Resources, or
>   else it will not compile.)
>
> Example:
>
> Suppose that your application's
>   default language is English. Suppose
>   also that you want to localize all the
>   text in your application to French,
>   and most of the text in your
>   application (everything except the
>   application's title) to Japanese. In
>   this case, you could create three
>   alternative strings.xml files, each
>   stored in a locale-specific resource
>   directory:
>
> 1. res/values/strings.xml
>        Contains English text for all the strings that the application uses,
>      including text for a string named
>      title.
> 2. res/values-fr/strings.xml
>        Contain French text for all the strings, including title.
> 3. res/values-ja/strings.xml
>        Contain Japanese text for all the strings except title.
>
> If your Java code refers to
>   R.string.title, here is what will
>   happen at runtime:
>
> ```
> * If the device is set to any language other than French, Android
> ```
>
> will load title from the
>   res/values/strings.xml file.
>       * If the device is set to French, Android will load title from the
>   res/values-fr/strings.xml file.
>
> Notice that if the device is set to
>   Japanese, Android will look for title
>   in the res/values-ja/strings.xml file.
>   But because no such string is included
>   in that file, Android will fall back
>   to the default, and will load title in
>   English from the
>   res/values/strings.xml file.

To change the localization of your application, you can use the following code snippet:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Configuration newConfig = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
// newConfig.locale = Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE;
newConfig.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
res.updateConfiguration(newConfig, null);
```

Comment: But localization shall change the phone language i need to change only my specific application language change

Comment: @ruby: So the real problem is not the localization of your application but to change the locale only inthe application scope and not the phone scope?

Comment: Hi to be precise i am working on a Voice Recognition application where user can select any Language like English and Japanese and then give voice commands in that language: eg: If i say Mail in English my application should open my inbox and if any other user says in Japanese than that request should be accepted

Answer (score 0):

Just put a simple drop-down for English and Japanese if you select English use the following code.And Don't forget to add the different strings with the particular values folder for eg. values-es

```
       String languageToLoad  = "es";
       Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
       Locale.setDefault(locale);
       Configuration config = new Configuration();
       config.locale = locale;
       getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
       getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

And for Japnese replace the string **languageToLoad** with Japnese code as **(ja-jp)**.